# Iterating through a list and passing each value to a function in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list, function, iteration

I have a list of IP addresses and I wish to use a Netmiko function to connect to each of these IP's in turn..

The function has IP as the first parameter, but I am not sure how to run through the list, passing each value as the first required parameter.

I have got this far:

```
    def find_mac(ip,username,password)

    ip_list = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']
    for i in ip_list:
       find_mac(list[0],username,password)
```

which will use the first list item for each iteration (as expected) but how would I go about using the next list item each time it iterates through the list?

So first it connectes to 1.1.1.1, then 2.2.2.2 etc...

I'm sure this is straight forward, and I'm sorry if my terminology is a bit off... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_mac(ip, username, password):
    # some magic
    return something

ip_list = ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']
uname = "myawesomeusername"
pwd = "hunter2"
for ip in ip_list:
    print(find_mac(ip, uname, pwd))
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I've implemented this and it is now doing exactly what I wanted :)